# Validating the existence of a HABTM model relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

    validates_presence_of :category_ids
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :businesses
end
```

I am setting the relationship through the business creation form, using the `category_ids` attribute.

I tried using `validates_presence_of`, however, this is not validating the existence of a category.

I can manipulate the form through the browser, give a non-existing ID for a category. After submitting the form, I get an error:

```
Couldn't find Category with id=181723
```

---

Edit:

Added the following custom validation method, but I am still getting the same error, as if the validation was not being run.

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

    validate :categories_exist

    def categories_exist
      category_ids.each do |c|
        errors.add(:category_ids, :category_doesnt_exist) unless Category.exists? c
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a variety of ways you could achieve this but I'd recommend looking at [Custom Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) and [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [validates_existence](https://github.com/perfectline/validates_existence) gem. This gem has been very useful to me for validating if foreign keys correspond to legitimate parent records. As described in the readme:

> This plugin library adds ActiveRecord models a way to check if a
>   :belongs_to association actually exists upon saving.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to validate existence of HATBM associations